# Remove line breaks in Bourne Shell from variable

Tags: shell, scripting, newline, line-breaks, sh

In bourne shell I have the following:

```
VALUES=`some command that returns multiple line values`

echo $VALUES
```

Looks like:

```
"ONE"
"TWO"
"THREE"
"FOUR"
```

I would like it to look like:

```
"ONE" "TWO" "THREE" "FOUR"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want an array of 4 strings, or do you want the single string "ONE TWO THREE FOUR"?

Comment: nit: The command in backticks (why not use $() instead?) does not 'return' multiple values.  It outputs multiple lines, and returns a single value, hopefully zero.

Comment: William, very simplified version. I actually take the output of the backticks, do some parse work on the data in VALUES than output VALUES later.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`echo $VALUES | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: Nice. Just a tweak: in bash and zsh at least you can pipe in the env var without echo with <<<, i.e. tr '\n' ' ' <<< $VALUES.

Comment: @liwp +1 for the nice tip. BTW how to pass escaped string using `<<<` i.e. `tr -d '\n' <<< "a line with line feed \n"`. the string doesn't escape '\n' in the double quote as I expected, any idea?

Comment: If you don't want the spaces you can do `echo $VALUES | tr -d '\n'`, the result would be `ONETWOTHREEFOUR`

Answer (score 2):

Another method, if you want to not just print out your code but assign it to a variable, and not have a spurious space at the end:

```
$ var=$(tail -1 /etc/passwd; tail -1 /etc/passwd)
$ echo "$var"
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
$ var=$(echo $var)
$ echo "$var"     
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me (on OS X Yosemite). This is what I used:

`echo -n $VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `xargs` (which keeps a final newline though - instead of a possible trailing space using `tr`):

```
echo $VALUES | xargs
printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs
```

@yozloy: how to pass escaped string using `<<<`

```
tr -d '\n' <<< "`printf '%b' 'a line with line feed \n'`"
```