# Remove line feed in CSV using Unix script

Tags: unix

I have a CSV file and I want to remove the all line feeds (LF or \n) which are all coming in between the double quotes alone.

Can you please provide me an Unix script to perform the above task. I have given the input and expected output below.

**Input :**

No,Status,Date

1,"Success

Error",1/15/2018

2,"Success

Error

NA",2/15/2018

3,"Success

Error",3/15/2018

**Expected output:**

No,Status,Date

1,"Success Error",1/15/2018

2,"Success Error NA",2/15/2018

3,"Success Error",3/15/2018

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write everything for you, as I am not sure about your system as well as which bash version that is running on it. But here are a couple of suggestions that you might want to consider.

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/31021-removing-line-breaks-shell-variable.html

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/19484-remove-line-feeds.html

[How to remove carriage return from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-carriage-return-from-a-string-in-bash/19345906)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57124/remove-newline-from-unix-variable

[Remove line breaks in Bourne Shell from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103030/remove-line-breaks-in-bourne-shell-from-variable)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254644/how-do-i-remove-newline-character-at-the-end-of-file

https://serverfault.com/questions/391360/remove-line-break-using-awk